# MERGE in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, sql-merge

Is there a way to call [T-Sql's MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) command from .NET Entity framework 4?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No there no such built-in functionality - you must build your own. Very common is for example approach like:

```
public void SaveOrUpdate(MyEntity entity)
{
    if (entity.Id == 0)
    {
        context.MyEntities.AddObject(entity);
    }
    else
    {
        context.MyEntities.Attach(entity);
        context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
    }

    // You can call SaveChanges here or you can call it separately after multiple changes
}
```

This is example for working with detached entity which have `Id` auto generated in the database (`IDENTITY`). Default Id for new entity is always 0 because the real value will be assigned during saving changes.

Comment: thanks, however When using DDD and you are attaching an Aggregate root, with a few levels of nesting of properties, then one would need to do some form or recursion. Is there some example of that? (It also bit puzzling that EF team expects devs to handle this common scenario themselves, when other orms such as NHibernate offer merge out of the box)

Comment: But what if you don't already know if the object exists in the database? The `MERGE` statement is precisely for determining if the object exists or not, and updating or inserting *as needed*.

Comment: You miss the delete part.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank That's what `if (entity.Id == 0)` is for; presumably in the database Id starts at 1.