# Is there any simple way to implement the merge query of SQL Server in Linq?

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, merge, entity-framework-4.1

Is there any simple way to implement the merge query of SQL Server in Linq?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add a concrete example of a query you'd like to rewrite?

Comment: Are you looking for the Union method? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx

Comment: @rsbarro Nope. Just the Merge command in MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such built in functionality because the basis of LINQ is to query object models.  However, it's not too hard to build it.

- [MERGE in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842125/linq-t-sql-merge-like-function-entity-framework) (this example uses the Entity Framework)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkk7s5zk.aspx (this is an example of how it can be done using the ADO.NET DataTable -- interestingly enough this is a pretty good example from Microsoft)