# What is the return value of Database.ExecuteSqlCommand?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Modifying an answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916453/how-can-i-use-use-entity-framework-to-do-a-merge-when-i-dont-know-if-the-record) slightly, suppose I run this code:

```
public int SaveOrUpdate(MyEntity entity)
{
    var sql =  @"MERGE INTO MyEntity
                USING 
                (
                   SELECT   @id as Id
                            @myField AS MyField
                ) AS entity
                ON  MyEntity.Id = entity.Id
                WHEN MATCHED THEN
                    UPDATE 
                    SET     Id = @id
                            MyField = @myField
                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                    INSERT (Id, MyField)
                    VALUES (@Id, @myField);"

    object[] parameters = {
        new SqlParameter("@id", entity.Id),
        new SqlParameter("@myField", entity.myField)
    };
    return context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, parameters);
}
```

This will actually run and it returns an int. What does the int mean? The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.113).aspx) just says

> The result returned by the database after executing the command.

I did a couple tests and it looks like it's 1 if it modified a row, and 0 if nothing changed. Is the return value the number of rows modified?

Comment: Any SQL Execute returns the number of rows Affected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For most databases, that means the number of rows affected by the command. I theory though, god forbid that such a thing exists, the database vendor is free to return whatever and you would then need to look in the documentation for the particular database for what the number means.