# Deleting and Re-Inserting Child Entities using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Hi I'm trying to workout a simple example of Course and Tags with Entity Framework.

One **Course** can have Multiple **Tag**s associated with it (Many to Many)

What i want to achieve is a method **`UpdateTags( int courseId , IEnumerable<Tag> tags )`**.
It should clear all the existing Tags (it should to maintain new order of tags) and add the new set of tags passed (it can contain both existing tags and new tags). It should create any new Tags passed (Id = 0) and only create association in the CourseTags junction table for existing Tags (Id > 0).

I tried many options came up with below.

**What i came up with**

```cs
static void UpdateTags(int courseId, IEnumerable < Tag > tags) {
  using(var context = new PlutoDBConnection()) {
    var c = context.Courses.Include("Tags").Single(t =>t.Id == courseId);
    foreach(var t in tags) {
      if (t.Id <= 0) {
        c.Tags.Add(t);
      }
      else {
        if (!c.Tags.Select(x =>x.Id).ToList().Contains(t.Id)) {
          c.Tags.Add(t);
        }
        context.Tags.Attach(t);
      }
    }

    var tagsToRemove = new List < Tag > ();
    foreach(var v in c.Tags) {
      if (!tags.Select(x =>x.Id).ToList().Contains(v.Id)) {
        tagsToRemove.Add(v);
      }
    }

    foreach(var b in tagsToRemove) {
      c.Tags.Remove(b);
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

I find this as inefficient to contain many loops.

How can i achieve this with more efficiently. Is there any simpler way to do this in Entity Framework without much manual checks?

Here is my model classes

**Course**

```cs
public partial class Course
{
   public Course()
   {
      this.Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
   }
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public int AuthorId { get; set; }
   public CourseLevel Level { get; set; }
   public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

**Tag**

```cs
public partial class Tag
{
   public Tag()
   {
      this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
   }
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string TagText { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the `CourseTags` table as an entity in your model as well?

Comment: @Progman Not in model

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916453/how-can-i-use-use-entity-framework-to-do-a-merge-when-i-dont-know-if-the-record#answer-26977841

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty this is using custom queries and im affraid it is more complex